# After login.aspx to default.aspx, then how do i know who just login? == Masterpage.LoginName1.UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

After login.apsx to default.aspx, then how do i know who just login? I have a login control in masterpage, because i want to do a linq var using logined username as "Where" parameter!

on my master page:

after login.aspx to default.apsx, i have a query in the code-behind file, just want to extract the data for this specific user who justed login.

```
var query = from uM in db.aspnet_Memberships
                    join uD in db.UserDetails
                    on uM.UserId equals uD.UserId
                    join u in db.aspnet_Users
                    on uM.UserId equals u.UserId
                    join jL in db.JobLists
                    on uM.UserId equals jL.UserId
                    where u.UserName == Masterpage.LoginName1.UserName

                select new { jL.JobId, 
                             jL.JobTitle,
                             jL.Summary,
                             jL.Detail,
                             jL.CompanyName,
                             jL.CompanyEmail,
                             jL.PostDate,
                             uD.City, 
                             uD.State, 
                             uD.Country,
                             u.UserName,
                             jL.IsTop
                };
```

this gives syntax error where u.UserName == Masterpage.LoginName1.UserName
thanks for advance!

Comment: let me know when you have found solution please

Answer (score 2):

User.identity.name or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding with asp.net you can use MembershipServices and RoleServices. And it is not goog idea to get parameter from master page. If you will use membershipservice. Later you can simply cal it's methods and get currenc logged user.

[here is link to learn how to use this services](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083524/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121405-1.aspx)

if you will use it you can simply the call User.Identity.Name and get current user name

Comment: on my master page i have a loginstatus <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="You are
logged in as: {0}" />
             <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />

Comment: yes i understand you. But i adviced you to use this services. This services will also work with asp:LoginStatus and with another aspx controls.

Comment: if Joakim's method works it meand that you are using Services. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Your loginpage can save the username to the session

```
   this.Session["Usename"] = ....
```

and your query logic retrieves it from there.